# Facebook Firebase Not Storing Identifier

Tags: facebook, firebase, react-native, authentication, firebase-authentication

For some random users I get no identifier for some users?  The only thing I could possibly think of would be apple testing when I release the app (but then there is no google and I use google, email, and facebook, and they all link together?).

None of the userID's are in my database either.

[image]

Comment: 2 questions: 1. Do any of these facebook accounts contain any email? 2. are you using multiple accounts per email setting in your Firebase Auth project settings?

Comment: Those don't have an email just a -, all my other facebook accounts show emails.  I am using email/password, google, and facebook

Comment: This is starting to cause a lot of problems.  How would I figure out how to debug this issue?

Comment: Can you provide answers to my 2 questions. Facebook accounts can be created with phone numbers, or Facebook users could choose not to share their emails. Also are you using multiple accounts per email setting in your project?

Comment: @bojeil to be honest, I have no idea how I would even search this for #1.  There are no emails tied to these as far as I can see.  I think it is a phone number issue potentially like you said.  #2 they can NOT have multiple accounts per email